# Show debug banner on Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-xml

I am trying to display the little debug banner in the top right of the app just like Flutter does but in Android.

[image]

What is the best way to implement this? I just want it on this activity.

Comment: I don't think there is any direct way cause it platform specific i guess .. Just use the link above and put a view in your layout ..

Comment: You can create a view and add it to your layout with just one condition if BuildConfig.DEBUG. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Yeah okay it's what I thought. Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### How to draw behind the status bar?

Make the app draw behind the status bar by setting the following flags in your theme.

```
 <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Use [fitsSystemWindows](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:fitsSystemWindows) property inside each activity layout xml to determine which content should go behind the statusbar and which content should go below the statusbar. So here in your case, the debug banner should go behind the translucent statusbar. Create the xml file for the activity like that way.

### How to rotate the view?

Just use the rotate attribute as shown in the below sample snippet

```
<View
android:rotation="45"
... />
```

### How to determine whether it is debug build or release build?

Use the BuildConfig.DEBUG flag

Answer (score 2):

U can check build is debug mode or release mode using BuildConfig.

```
if(BuildConfig.DEBUG){
 // show banner 
}else{
 // not show banner 
}
```

[OR U will find a library in android arsenal](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/7090)